# What is the best pkcs11 installation for Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pkcs#11

I am working on incorporating pkcs11 on my Ubuntu 16.04 workstation. I noticed a few installs available - opensc, libengine and so on.

Can anyone please suggest me what the best pkcs11 install is ? I need to do the bare minimum stuff with it , nothing too fancy.

The instructions to download would be very helpful as well and if there are any code examples available that would be a great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is it you want to accomplish?

PKCS#11 is really just a standard API middleware exposes for accessing their capabilities. You can, for example, call into an HSM using the associated PKCS#11 library without opensc or other middleware.

Think of OpenSC as a set of tools for working with smart cards, one of the tools being a PKCS#11 library that can talk to numerous smart cards. For example, ones that implement the PIV card-edge/protocol.

On Linux, in general, you will probably need to use OpenSC to work with the most common cards as many rely on it for Linux support.

libengine, on the other hand, is a plug-in model for OpenSSL that allows you to load a PKCS#11 library in OpenSSL. This allows you to take an application designed for OpenSSL and get it to work with an HSM or smart card (in some cases).

It is turtles all the way down.

Comment: Hi rmhrisk, I want to use pkcs11 in my application and use the functions it provides to generate keys, store keys etc within my application. So I essentially want to replace the HSM hardware with my application. What do you suggest ?

Comment: What language is your application written in?

Comment: rmhrisk - C and C++

Comment: Then you will be able to call the PKCS#11 library for the device you choose directly and you do not need anything from the operating system, that is beyond the dependencies that library carries. If you want to practice without a device check out SoftHSM.